# how to join two tables using MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce

I have two tables  employees and salaries like this

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (  
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  `hire_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `salaries` (
`emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
`from_date` date NOT NULL,
`to_date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`from_date`),
KEY `emp_no` (`emp_no`),
CONSTRAINT `salaries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How can we join these two tables using map reduce program, can you please provide the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by following these steps :

1. Extract the data from both table in csv file.
2. Read both the files in mapper and make key as you primary key (emp_no).
3. Write the putput of the reducer in the csv format to a file.
4. Import the file with mysql bulk import command.

If you have data generated dynamically in the tables then extract only the generated data from each tables for step 1